# Displaying server message from $asyncValidators

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to send asynchronous validations. How do I display an error message fetched from server via `$asyncValidators`?

I have a `validateName` directive which uses `$asyncValidators` to validate `user.name` at the server. If the validation fails, the server responds with an `errorMessage`.

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('validateName', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$asyncValidators.name = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if( ctrl.$dirty ) {
          return $http.post('/validate-username', {username: viewValue}).then(function(response) {
            if (!response.data.validUsername) {
              return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
            }
            return true;
          });
        } else {
          return $q.resolve(true);
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Below is my input field that uses the directive. I would like to display the `errorMessage` below that field.

```
<input name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" validate-name>
<!-- Here I would like to display the errorMessage somehow -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback from your directive to send that message to your controller, then you can bind that message string to your DOM as you like

1. in your html add an attribute that will hold a reference to a function in your controller that will accept the error message from your directive and show it.

`<input name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" get-error="showError" validate-name>`

2. in your controller add the `showError(message)` function

   ```
   $scope.showError = function(message) {
       $scope.showMessage = message;
   }
   ```
3. in your directive, you should call that callback function when you create the error message

   ```
   // test if the var is actually a function reference before running it
   if (angular.isFunction(scope.getError()) {
        // this will run the function over at your controller
        scope.getError()("This is error");
   }
   ```

Comment: I get an error: `scope.getError is not a function`. If I rename `$scope.showError` to `$scope.getError`, I get rid of the problem, but nothing shows up in view.

Comment: `scope.getError` is not a function, but `scope.getError()` is a function, the directive's scope (you can also do this using the & attribute in the directive definition object) provides you a curry function that returns the function in your controller

Answer (score 0):

I ended up assigning the error message to the scope. Something like `scope.form[attrs.name]['errorMessages'] = response.data.errors`.